# Set Configurable product attribute Magento API

Tags: c#, magento

Long time reader but first question.

I've research over and over for this answer but could not get one. I'm creating a configurable product via the Magento API SOAP V2 over C#.

I have a an Attribute "Size" which is used to create the configurable product (option "Use To Create Configurable Product" is selected Yes)

Where in the API can I specify that "Size" will be used as config_attributes for my configurable product?

All that I've found so far is related to attribute sets which is a different subjet (I believe)

Thank you community! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the answer. Please see post below:

http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/

The API is modified via an extension to allow addition of the super attribute configurable_attributes to a configurable product.

Hope I can help somebody with this input.

Thanks to Johann Reinke for this extension!